# Manage at least three thread in JavaFx

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, javafx, runnable

I'm trying to configure my server to manage at least 3 client, but when I do it I get an Out of memory error even before connecting the first one. How can I improve it? In `ThreadedEchoHandler()` I've the part where I accept the request of the client and the run method which contains all the thing that the server has to do.

```
public void initModel() throws IOException {
    contenutoTextArea.append("Waiting for connections\n");
    textarea.setText(contenutoTextArea.toString());
    s = new ServerSocket(5000);
    while (true) {
        Runnable r = new ThreadedEchoHandler();
        new Thread(r).start();
    }
}
```

EDIT: start of the ThreadedEchoHandler:

```
lass ThreadedEchoHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket incoming;

    private String nomeAccount = "";

    public void run() {
        try {
            incoming = s.accept();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to accept requests");
        }
    }
```

Comment: But you are starting unlimited ammount of threads here.

Comment: @Antoniossss I updated the question with the part where I accept the requests. Should I move the loop there?

Comment: You should rather accept in loop and start thread upon incoming connection not the other way around. Right now you are starting unlimited threads at once. No wonder you are running out of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the `accept` in the same thread where the `while` loop happens, and then, after having a new accepted connection, start a new thread:

```
while (true) {
    Socket incoming = s.accept();
    Runnable r = new ThreadedEchoHandler(incoming);
    new Thread(r).start();
}
```

And modify `ThreadEchoHandler` to get its `Socket` from outside:

```
class ThreadedEchoHandler implements Runnable {
    final private Socket incoming;
    private String nomeAccount = "";

    ThreadedEchoHandler(Socket incoming) {
        this.incoming = incoming;
    }

    public void run() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Of course you can organize it in various ways, like `ThreadedEchoHandler` could launch its thread from the constructor, or even do the `accept` too, but again, it has to happen *before* starting the thread:

```
class ThreadedEchoHandler implements Runnable {
    final private Socket incoming;
    private String nomeAccount = "";

    ThreadedEchoHandler(ServerSocket serv) throws IOException {
        incoming = serv.accept();
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

then the loop could be this:

```
while (true) new ThreadedEchoHandler(s);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, there is only a problem: the GUI of the server doesn't load (the clients work)

Comment: Having a `while(true)` loop in the GUI thread never works, so this accepting thing should go in its own thread. However, a rule of thumb is that regardless of the framework, GUI things are always preferred to happen in the GUI thread - refer [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) for the case of JavaFX.